# Is "less than eager" a native English idiom?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I'm sure I've read the "less than eager" expression a couple of times, but without being a native English speaker I can't tell for sure if that's an English idiom or a literal translation of an idiom from another language.

A quick search for "less than eager""usage" returned multiple translations engines offers to translate it to various languages as top results. It's never a good sign.

So, is this a less known native English idiom? If not, is there a more appropriate one which I could use?

Comment: Native English speaker here.  I certainly have heard it, and have used it myself.  I've no idea from where it originates, but it is certainly heard in at least my dialect (Canadian) of English.

Comment: I've always heard it used ironically, and it's good English: "They offered me the job at low wages, and I was less than eager to accept."

Comment: @YosefBaskin you've *always* heard it used ironically? Surely that's not true ... this is a fairly popular English usage, and it definitely doesn't have to be used ironically.

Comment: How is that usage ironic, @Yosef?

Comment: @CodyGray - Since I would be unhappy if I needed a job enough to take it at low wages, saying 'less than eager' is a vast understatement. So while I pretend I may be almost eager or close to it, I am actually far from it and expressing it ironically. Of course, 'less than' is neutral -- I could be happy with many things when they're 'less than perfect.'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's idiomatic, but it's not an idiom—a phrase or usage whose meaning is not determined by the meanings of its parts. You can use *less than* readily with just about any adjective which denotes a measurable quality:

> less than eager
>   less than perfect
>   less than unanimous

As the Comments suggest, *less than eager* is ordinarily used in an ironically understated sense more or less equivalent to *strongly averse*.

Comment: Mistaking _idiomatic_ for _idiom_. My non-native speaker background is showing, haha. Thanks for the correction and for the answer!

Comment: @Nihal It's a very confusing pair of terms. Alas, terminology for just about every aspect of English grammar is a mess right now!

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't describe it as an *idiom*, but it's certainly idiomatic. It's used with other adjectives too. The relevant definition of [**less**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/less) is:

> (**less than**) far from; certainly not:
>   *Mitch looked less than happy*

I can't tell you why a regular Google search behaves like that, but I had more luck finding examples of usage with a [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q="less+than+eager"&oq="less+than+eager").

Comment: Look man, do not bring me into this.

Comment: @Mitch I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: @Mitch What's wrong? You seem sad...

Comment: @Laurel: \*cough\* look at the username \*cough\* look at the example in your answer *ahem*...

Comment: In hindsight I should have put a little more effort into finding examples by searching "less" first. Thank you for the tip, I actually forgot Google Books existed.